# Clarification re: Nazgul and characters, can you attack them as a single?

Tags: war-of-the-ring

I haven't played War of the Ring yet - I'm reading through the rules and I have a question that needs clarifying.

For ordinary Free People leaders, they always have to be with an army, so that's simple, and no worries

For Nazgul however, the rules (2nd edition, p8) say:

> The Nazgul are not obliged to be part of a friendly Army and can move on their own, flying to any region (even regions containing Free Peoples units) on the game board with a single movement.

And regarding characters, both Free Peoples and Shadow:

> In game terms, Characters act much the same as Leaders, but they do not suffer the same restrictions and can move on the game board on their own, ignoring the presence of enemy Armies.

Now as I understand it, leaders and characters don't offer any combat strength themselves. All they're good for is rerolls (and character abilities).

The question I have then, say the Shadow player flies their Nazgul to adjacent the current known location of the ringbearers, but then Free Peoples player musters and moves some armies:

Does this result in combat? The Nazgul having no combat strength, it instantly dying?

Same goes for Characters. Say the Free People player has split off some companions and they're heading toward a city and get caught by a Shadow army, do they instantly die?

Or does the army just occupy the same territory and no combat ensues?

Answer (score 1):

Combat can only occur between 2 armies. Companions or minions by themselves do not form an army. They are only part of an army if there are friendly army units in the same region.
They cannot be killed when they are in a region without friendly army units. (Except when specifically mentioned on a card, like the Ent-cards kill Saruman)
They are perfectly fine walking (or flying) about in the same region as characters or armies of the opposing side.

> The question I have then, say the Shadow player flies their Nazgul to adjacent the current known location of the ringbearers, but then Free Peoples player musters and moves some armies:
>
> Does this result in combat? The Nazgul having no combat strength, it instantly dying?

No. Nothing happens. There are no Shadow units in the region, so the Nazgul are not part of an army. Nazgul and Leaders are not units. They can never be in combat by themselves; only when together with Army units.

Comment: Could you clarify this? It is a bit hard to understand this in relation to the question as it seems strange that a unit can move by itself but be protected from combat.

Comment: Nazgul and Leaders are not units.

Comment: You should clarify by putting that information in the answer not in a comment